# If I'm lapping valves do I need to replace piston rings?

Tags: engine, vw, valve

I just removed the head and am lapping valves because of timing problem. If I'm lapping valves, do I need to replace my piston rings too or not?

Car: 2010 Passat CC 1.8 TSI, 100,000 km

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not. One has nothing to do with the other. If there are *reasons* to change the piston rings, then by all means change them. Things like blowby and/or oil consumption would be reasons. Not because you pulled the head and are lapping valves.